# How to check if system update is available

Tags: android, system

Sometimes on my phone there is notification for system update. Is there some snippet of code for checking  if system update is available ?

or is there something that I can do in code to force check for system update available ?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a crazy idea that probably won't work, but have you tried a outgoing call intent with a phone number of `*#*#2432546#*#*`?

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to call your server and get the information.

Simply, you can get small xml file from the server and get the newest version number available and check that against the installed app version. If there is one available, you may notify a popup and direct the user to the Android market screen to update the app.

Comment: OP is looking for notifications about OEM firmware updates, not app updates from Market, I believe.